# 20 non-stop pushups vs 30 with short breaks?

Tags: training, push-ups

So I was wondering what would be more effective and make you stronger, 20 pushups without stopping, or 30 pushups with a 10 second break between each 10? So for example if I chose to do one of these three separate times a day, which one would make me stronger in one month?

Comment: @Craig i really wonder how can you, also, suggest protein for a person who asks only about doing pushups. You can talk about proper training and proper nutrtion (where you can say about protein) and not just that. Please, stop the missinform and make a complete statement for what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

Do the 20. Although I'd still suggest that you make it a bit more challenging (back pack, one leg up, kids sitting on you, etc). I'm making the assumption that your push-up is perfectly formed to challenge you fully. Also, the answer is based on your specific question. If the question weren't as specific, I'd suggest some more work.

Reasons is simply because 20 is roughly about 10-15 seconds, perhaps 20 seconds if you do them slowly. Provided the push-ups are perfectly clean and challenging, the amount of time is close to the sweet spot for alactic anaerobic phase. I'd suggest you do 3 sets each time with rests in between. You can read more on the timing of the phases here. [The Physiology of Training](http://www.saskcoach.ca/articles/training.html).

Dr. Tabata also did a number of studies in the 90's and found his magic numbers which were later popularly named the "Tabata Protocol." It's 20 seconds at 170% effort and 10 seconds active rest for a total of eight bouts.[Dr. Tabata Study via PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8897392)

This timed suggestion is only for push-ups per your question though. If you take it to a stack of weight, or up the pullup bar with a backpack, it'll be a different story

So why not the 10? As you can see, it's just not enough to induce a substantial demand on you. It may take you even less than 10 seconds.

To get more out of the push-ups, perhaps you may want to use time for non-rush, perfect ones in 20 seconds x 8 rounds, with exactly 10 seconds rest. This should be sufficiently challenging. As you get better and the work become easier, add some challenge such as keeping one leg raised (alternate), add weights or a back pack or a kid sitting on you.

I would highly recommend adding push-ups to a combination of work. For example, 20 pushups to a jump rope then a pull up bar, down to squat jumps or alternating side lunges and back to push-ups. Mix it up to add and address the full body work for more legs, core movements.